How to change link of a button based on which button on menu is clicked?
I'm trying to have a button change links when you click the buttons on the menu.
For example, I click button 1 and then I click the Link button it opens webpage 1, but then I click button 2 and then click the Link button, it is still webpage 1 that opens.
How do I make it to where it would change the links every time a button is pressed?
Here is what I had done so far, but after one button is clicked it doesn't change the link again, even when clicking the other button.
my code is here:
HTML:
<nav class= "menu">
  <li id="button1" onclick="button1()"> Page 1</li>
  <li id="button2" onclick="button2()">Page 2</li>
</nav>

<div>
  <li id="Link" href="#">View Page</li>
</div>

Javascript:
const bttn = document.getElementById("Link");

function button1(){
  bttn.addEventListener('click', function bttn3() {
  var url = "webpage1.html";
  window.open(url);
}

function button2(){
  bttn.addEventListener('click', function bttn3() {
  var url = "webpage2.html";
  window.open(url);
}


Your HTML is invalid : <li> element doesn't have a href attribute.

Your HTML has many errors...
A simplest way is about using a data attribute


const
  bttn    = document.querySelector('#Link')
, menuElm = document.querySelector('menu')
  ;
menuElm.addEventListener('click', e =>  // use event delegation
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li[data-url]')) return
  
  bttn.dataset.url = e.target.dataset.url;
  bttn.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  })
bttn.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  let url = `https://${bttn.dataset.url}`;
  // window.open( url );
  console.clear();
  console.log(`window.open( ${url} ) is not supported on SO snippet`);
  })
li { cursor: pointer; }
<menu> <!-- use menu element, nav element doesn't accept li -->
  <li data-url="developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web"> mozilla </li>
  <li data-url="stackoverflow.com/help/"> help !</li>
</menu>

<ol>  <!-- don't use div element, it doesn't accept li -->
  <li id="Link" dat-url="#">View Page</li>
</ol>




Note: Place JavaScript code after HTML code.


var url = "";

document.getElementById("Link").addEventListener('click', function(){
  //window.open(url);
  alert(url);
});

function button1(){
  url = "webpage1.html";
}

function button2(){
  url = "webpage2.html";
}
<nav class= "menu">
  <li id="button1" onclick="button1()"> Page 1</li>
  <li id="button2" onclick="button2()">Page 2</li>
</nav>

<div>
  <li id="Link" href="#">View Page</li>
</div>



